# How do I save textboxes with tabs depending which tab is open?

Tags: vb.net, tabs, textbox, save

#### I am trying to create a document writer in vb.net

So I decided to add a tab control, so I can create a new tab when I press a button. I would like to save the text in the tab that is open. I created a function the returns the text depending on what tab is open, but that only works for the two default tabs. I don't know how I would save if I've created a new tab.

The function to get the text is this:

```
Public Function getText() As String
If tabPage1.Visible = True Then
Return mainText.Text
ElseIf tabPage2.Visible = True Then
Return textBox1.Text
End If
End Function
```

I've done some research online, I've even looked at SharpDevelop's source code and I couldn't find anything.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT :

```
Public Sub setText(Byval value As String)
  If tabPage1.Visible = True Then
     mainText.Text = value
  ElseIf tabPage2.Visible = True Then
     textBox1.Text = value
  End If
End Sub
```

Does anyone know how I would do an open feature determined on what tab is open (as before.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to have a textbox in each of your tabPages generated dynamically. If this is the case you could generalize your GetText function with this code

```
Function GetText() As String
    If tabControl1.SelectedTab IsNot Nothing Then
        Return tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().First().Text
    End If

End Function
```

This requires that you have at least one textbox in each page (and your TabControl is named *tabControl1*). The [SelectedTab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab(v=vs.110).aspx) property (if not nothing) is the current tabPage displayed by your tabControl

Comment: I tried your solution but I got this error "'OfType' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection'." Do you know how to fix this? @Steve

Comment: Controls.OfType requires the Linq namespace added to your program. Use Imports Linq

Comment: I added Imports Linq to the top, but I still get the same error @Steve

Comment: Sorry, _Imports System.Linq_

Comment: Above where? If you have another question then it is better to write a new question.

Comment: Oh ok, [New post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34244001/how-do-i-open-a-file-into-a-textbox-with-multiple-tabs) @Steve