# How do I open a file into a textbox with multiple tabs?

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I'm creating a document writing program in VB.NET, and I can create multiple tabs. How would I open a file into the textbox that I am open on, even though I can't declare what textbox I'm using? [Link to understand this better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241621/how-do-i-save-textboxes-with-tabs-depending-which-tab-is-open)

Code for the sub:

```
Public Sub setText(Byval value As String)
  If tabPage1.Visible = True Then
    mainText.Text = value
  ElseIf tabPage2.Visible = True Then
    textBox1.Text = value
  End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the same type of idea you did for the getText

```
Dim sub setText(value as string)
  Dim mytextbox As TextBox = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)().First()

  mytextbox.text = value
end sub
```